# JS Problem with Multiple Forms working using 1 JS file

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This is following on from:

[JS Form validation Checkbox IF statement not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66617809/js-form-validation-checkbox-if-statement-not-working)

I've added another separate form for the business owners.
Currently I have a separate html file for 'business' & 'customer'. I've put the CSS for both forms in one file and also the JS is all in one file.

*Problem :* I seem to only be able to get one form to work at the moment, although if I take the forms out and separate them into different projects they work fine, independently, on different platforms or workspaces.
What I'm trying to do is get the one JS file to reference both forms & execute commands based on what page the user is on filling out the form (business or customer). The problem is only Customer Form works when the JS is all in one file, the Business Form doesn't work (ie show the red highlighted errors). If I take the Business Form out and put it in another stand alone project (inc the HTML, CSS & JS) it works fine. Seems to be a conflict with the Form reference?
I need 2 forms as I will be expanding on fields etc, but to keep things simple I've thrown up samples of both on here.

Here is the **HTML for the 'Business'** form, (customer form HTML is in the link -and yes it has been changed to work properly):

```
 <div class="business-contactus-body">
    <div class="business_container">
        <div class="business_contactus_heading_form">
            <h2>Business client Form</h2>
        </div>
        <form id="business_contactus_form" class="business_contactus_form">
            <div class="business-form-control">
                <label for="businessName">Name</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="ABC Company" id="businessName" />
                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                <small>Error message</small>
            </div>
            <div class="business-form-control">
                <label for="businessEmail">Email</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="a@abccompany.com" id="businessEmail" />
                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                <small>Error message</small>
            </div>
            <div class="business-form-control">
                <label for="businessMessage">Message</label>
                <textarea type="text" placeholder="Please enter a brief message" id="businessMessage" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
                <i class="fas fa-check-circle"></i>
                <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                <small>Error message</small>
            </div>
            <div class="business-form-control">
                <input class="businessDisclaimerBox" type="checkbox" id="businessDisclaimerBox" />
                <label for="businessDisclaimerBox" id="disclaimer-label">I agree to the terms and conditions.</label>
                <small>Error message</small>
             </div>
             <button class="contactus_form_button">Submit</button>
         </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS - for both forms**

```
  /***** CONTACT US PAGE CSS *****/

  * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .customer-contactus-body, business-contactus-body {
      min-height: 1300px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: pink;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      margin: 0px;
  }

  .customerCU-contactus-heading-message,   .business-contactus-heading-message {
      width: 600px;
      font-weight: 200;
      margin: -50px 0px 50px 20px;
      padding: 0px;
  }

  .customerCU_container, .business_container {
      background-color: grey;
      border-radius: 5px;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 600px;
      max-width: 100%;
  }

  .customer_contactus_heading_form,   .business_contactus_heading_form {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
      background-color: white;
      padding: 20px 40px;
  }

  .customer_contactus_heading_form h2,   .business_contactus_heading_form h2 {
      margin: 0px;
      color: black;
  }

  .contactus_form, .business_contactus_form {
      padding: 30px 40px;
  }

  .customerCU-form-control, .business-form-control  {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      position: relative;
  }

  .customerCU-form-control label, .business-form-control label {
      display: inline-block;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      font-weight: 530;
      font-size: 17px;
  }

  .customerCU-form-control input, .business-form-control input {
      border: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
      border-radius: 4px;
      display: block;
      font-size: 14px;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 100%;
  }

  .customerCU-form-control input:focus, .business-form-control input:focus {
      outline: 0;
      border-color: grey;
  }

  .customerCU-form-control.success input, .business-form-control.success input {
      border-color: green;
  }

  .customerCU-form-control textarea,   .business-form-control textarea {
      resize: vertical;
      border: 2px solid #f0f0f0;
      border-radius: 4px;
      display: block;
      font-size: 14px;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 100%;
  }

  .customerCU-form-control.error input,   .business-form-control.error input {
      border-color: red;
  }

  .customerCU-form-control textarea:focus,   .business-form-control textarea:focus {
      outline: 0;
      border-color: grey;
  }

  .customerCU-form-control.success textarea,   .business-form-control.success textarea {
      border-color: green;
  }

  .customerCU-form-control.error textarea,   .business-form-control.error textarea {
      border-color: red;
  }

  .customerCU-form-control.error label#disclaimer-label,   .business-form-control.error label#disclaimer-label {
      color: red;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-decoration: underline;
  }

  .customerCU-form-control i,   .business-form-control i {
      visibility: hidden;
      position: absolute;
      top: 40px;
      right: 10px;
  }

  .customerCU-form-control.success i.fa-check-circle,   .business-form-control.success i.fa-check-circle {
      color: green;
      visibility: visible;
  }

  .customerCU-form-control.error i.fa-exclamation-circle,   .business-form-control.error i.fa-exclamation-circle {
      color: red;
      visibility: visible;
  }

  .customerCU-form-control small, .business-form-control small {
      color: red;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
  }

  .customerCU-form-control.error small, .business-form-control.error small {
      visibility: visible;
  }

  label#disclaimer-label {
      margin-left: 10px;
      font-size: 12px;
      width: 612px;
  }

  .contactus_form_button {
      background-color: rgb(31, 136, 229);
      border: 2px solid rgb(128, 128, 128, 0.199);
      border-radius: 4px;
      color: #fff;
      display: block;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-top: 20px;
      width: 100%;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: 0.3s ease background-color;
  }

  .contactus_form_button:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgb(25, 60, 173);
  }

  @keyframes contactus-form-status {
      0% {
          opacity: 1;
          pointer-events: all;
      }
      90% {
          opacity: 1;
          pointer-events: all;
      }
      100% {
          opacity: 0;
          pointer-events: none;
      }
  }
```

**JS**

```
//** CUSTOMER FORM **//
const form = document.getElementById('contactus_form');
const customerName = document.getElementById('customerName');
const customerCUEmail = document.getElementById('customerCUEmail');
const disclaimerBox = document.getElementById('disclaimerBox');

form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    checkInputs();
});

function checkInputs() {
    // trim to remove the whitespaces
    const customerNameValue = customerName.value.trim();
    const customerCUEmailValue = customerCUEmail.value.trim();
    
    if(customerNameValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(customerName, 'Please enter your name');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(customerName);
    }
    
    if(customerCUEmailValue === '') {
        setErrorFor(customerCUEmail, 'Email cannot be blank');
    } else if (!isEmail(customerCUEmailValue)) {
        setErrorFor(customerCUEmail, 'Not a valid email');
    } else {
        setSuccessFor(customerCUEmail);
    }
  
  if(!disclaimerBox.checked == true){
    setErrorFor(disclaimerBox, 'Please check box and accept our terms and conditions.');
  }else {
    setSuccessFor(disclaimerBox);
  }
}

function setErrorFor(input, message) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    const small = formControl.querySelector('small');
    formControl.className = 'customerCU-form-control error';
    small.innerText = message;
}

function setSuccessFor(input) {
    const formControl = input.parentElement;
    formControl.className = 'customerCU-form-control success';
}
    
function isEmail(customerCUEmail) {
    return /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(customerCUEmail);
}


// ** BUSINESS CLIENT FORM ** 
const business_contactus_form = document.getElementById('business_contactus_form');
const businessName = document.getElementById('businessName');
const businessEmail = document.getElementById('businessEmail');
const businessMessage = document.getElementById("businessMessage");
const businessDisclaimerBox = document.getElementById('businessDisclaimerBox');

business_contactus_form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    checkbusiness_Inputs();
});

function checkbusiness_Inputs() {
    //trim to remove the whitespaces
    const businessNameValue = businessName.value.trim();
    const businessEmailValue = businessEmail.value.trim();
    const businessMessageValue = businessMessage.value.trim();

    if (businessNameValue === '') {
        setErrorForB(businessName, 'Please enter your name');
    } else {
        setSuccessForB(businessName);
    }

   
    if (businessEmailValue === '') {
        setErrorForB(businessEmail, 'Email cannot be blank');
    } else if (!isEmailB(businessEmail)) {
        setErrorForB(businessEmail, 'Not a valid email');
    } else {
        setSuccessForB(businessEmail);
    }

    if (businessMessageValue === '') {
        setErrorForB(businessMessage, 'Please enter a message.');
    } else {
        setSuccessForB(businessMessage);
    }

    if (!businessDisclaimerBox.checked) {
        setErrorForB(businessDisclaimerBox, 'Please check box and accept terms and conditions.');
    } else {
        setSuccessForB(businessDisclaimerBox);
    }
}

function setErrorForB(input, message) {
    const formControlB = input.parentElement;
    const small = formControlB.querySelector('small');
    formControlB.className = 'business-form-control error';
    small.innerText = message;
}

function setSuccessForB(input) {
    const formControlB = input.parentElement;
    formControlB.className = 'business-form-control success';
}

function isEmailB(businessEmail) {
    return /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(businessEmail);
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error or issue with the one that doesn't work? You just said one works and one doesn't.

Comment: Basically both forms work (show red errors or green success when input is correct) fine when they are independently put on different workspaces or projects, but when I combine them on one JS file: the Customer form will work properly (show error: border highlight, icon etc) but the Business Form work. Let me know if that makes sense, I clarified above to make it a bit more clear

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. During the failure do you get any js errors in the console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:5501/Website/css/fontawesome/all.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

- And this one. Also getting this error on the form that is working

Comment: Any clue what these mean? As I've said, one form works perfectly fine, if the other is 'disabled' or if they are both separated into different workspaces/projects.

Comment: Ok. I figured out the problem. For some reason the JS file is only loading one function at a time and disabling the others. I added another script which works fine, but doesn't when i add it to the list of these ones. Seems like only the TOP or 1 function is being executed, any idea why this happens?